# Calling perl subroutines from the command line

Tags: perl, subroutine

Ok so i was wondering how i would go about calling a perl subroutine from the command line. So if my  program is Called test, and the subroutine is called fields i would like to call it from the command line like.

test fields

Comment: I think you need to give an example of the contents of `test`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a dispatch table.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub fields {
  say 'this is fields';
}

sub another {
  say 'this is another subroutine';
}

my %functions = (
  fields  => \&fields,
  another => \&another,
);

my $function = shift;

if (exists $functions{$function}) {
  $functions{$function}->();
} else {
  die "There is no function called $function available\n";
}
```

Some examples:

```
$ ./dispatch_tab fields
this is fields
$ ./dispatch_tab another
this is another subroutine
$ ./dispatch_tab xxx
There is no function called xxx available
```

Answer (score 10):

Look into [brian d foy's modulino pattern](http://www.drdobbs.com/scripts-as-modules/184416165) for treating a Perl file as both a module that can be used by other scripts or as a standalone program. Here's a simple example:

```
# Some/Package.pm
package Some::Package;
sub foo { 19 }
sub bar { 42 }
sub sum { my $sum=0; $sum+=$_ for @_; $sum }
unless (caller) {
    print shift->(@ARGV);
}
1;
```

Output:

```
$ perl Some/Package.pm bar
42
$ perl Some/Package.pm sum 1 3 5 7
16
```

Comment: This is huge overkill, since we don't really know what the OP has in mind

Comment: `print shift->(@ARGV) unless caller` is overkill?

Comment: `shift->(@ARGV)` would satisfy that interpretation of the OP's question, but I think we are a long way from understanding what is wanted. +1 anyway for an interesting reference

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that unless the subroutine is a built-in Perl operator, like `sqrt` for instance, when you could write

```
perl -e "print sqrt(2)"
```

or if it is provided by an installed module, say [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil), like this

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e "print shuffle 'A' .. 'Z'"
```

Comment: This seems like the best (only?) solution to use when you can't modify the Perl module itself.  A couple of caveats I've found which seem worth mentioning: 1. You can still run this on uninstalled modules (IE: ad-hoc Perl scripts), but you have to be in the directory where the module is and you have to set PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC=1 first.  2. This won't work with stateful subroutines (IE: methods or function which depend on global variables).

Answer (score 1):

here is an example:

```
[root@mat ~]# cat b.pm 
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
#
sub blah {
    print "Ahhh\n";
}
return 1
[root@mat ~]# perl -Mb -e "blah";
Ahhh
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the exact requirements, but this is a workaround you can use without much modifications in your code.

```
use Getopt::Long;
my %opts;
GetOptions (\%opts, 'abc', 'def', 'ghi');
&print_abc    if($opts{abc});
&print_def    if($opts{def});
&print_ghi    if($opts{ghi});


sub print_abc(){print "inside print_abc\n"}
sub print_def(){print "inside print_def\n"}
sub print_ghi(){print "inside print_ghi\n"}
```

and then call the program like :

```
perl test.pl -abc -def
```

Note that you can omit the unwanted options.