# Execute a Perl sub routine via the command prompt?

Tags: perl, cmd, subroutine

I have a perl (.pm) file with multiple sub routines. I want to execute one sub routine which takes a single parameter as argument. I tried

```
perl /full_file_path/file_name.pm mySubRoutine myArgument
```

but nothing was returned. What is the correct format?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23039028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Perl module is in one of the `@INC` list of directories then you can write

```
perl -Mfile_name -e 'mySubRoutine(myArgument)'
```

if it is elsewhere then you need to add the path, like

```
perl -M/full_file_path/file_name -e 'mySubRoutine(myArgument)'
```

and, as `ysth` points out, if the module file has a `package MyPackage` at the start then you may need to add that to your call, like

```
perl -M/full_file_path/file_name -e 'MyPackage::mySubRoutine(myArgument)'
```

however in that case the file should be called `MyPackage.pm` and the actual command would look something like below (notice that there is no `.pm` appended to filename when used with `-M` argument.

```
perl -M/full_file_path/MyPackage -e 'MyPackage::mySubRoutine(myArgument)'
```

Comment: possibly with a package qualifier, if the .pm truly means it is a module

Comment: I tried both with the package name and without but I get Unrecognized switch error

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so then you need double-quotes `"` instead of single ones

Comment: Yes, using a CMD window in Windows 7, but the file is running on Sun unit. With the double quotes I getting `Undefined subroutine &main::mySub called at -e line 1.`

Comment: Will it print the :returned" values to the screen? or I have to manually print it?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul you'll have to do that manually, e.g. `perl -MSome::Module -E'say for Some::Module::function()'` or `perl -MData::Dump -MSome::Module -e'dd Some::Module::function()'`.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: Then you need to add the correct package name as I said. It won't output anything unless you `print` it, so you want `print MyPackage::mySubroutine(myArgument)` inside the quotes