# Ways to call a function in Perl

Tags: perl, perlscript

Can I call a subroutine by taking its name dynamically as below?

```
printf "Enter subroutine name: ";
$var1 = <STDIN>;      # Input is E111;
$var1();
```

Function *E111*:

```
sub E111(){
    printf "Hi, this is E111 & Bye \n";
}
```

Is there a possibility to do it like this?

Comment: Follow the good advice of @zdim and use a dispatch table, but of course dynamic function calls are possible in perl: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling perl subroutines from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039028/calling-perl-subroutines-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 7):

There are very few hard limits on what you can do in Perl, but this is one of those places that you don't want to go to.  One normal way about it is to use a *dispatch table*

```
my %call = (
    'name_1' => sub { function body },   # inline, anonymous subroutine
    'name_2' => \&func,                  # or take a reference to a sub
    ...
);
```

where `sub {}` is an *anonymous subroutine*, so the value for `name_1` is a *code reference*.

Then you use it as

```
my $name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;

$call{$name}->(@arguments);  # runs the code associated with $name
```

This finds the key `$name` in the hash and dereferences its value, the coderef; so it runs that code.

Documentation: overview [perlintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html),   tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and references [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
print "Enter subroutine name:";

$var1 = <STDIN>;
chomp($var1);

eval "$var1()";

sub E111 {
    print "Hi this is E111 & Bye \n";
}
```